# Why do the following products of Pauli operators commute?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I've read in Mermin (https://doi.org/10.1063/1.2810588) that the operators $\hat{\sigma}_{y1} \hat{\sigma}_{x2} \hat{\sigma}_{x3}$, $\hat{\sigma}_{x1} \hat{\sigma}_{y2} \hat{\sigma}_{x3}$ and $\hat{\sigma}_{x1} \hat{\sigma}_{x2} \hat{\sigma}_{y3}$ all commute as "the product of any two of them differs from the product in the reverse order by an even number of such anti-commutations" (page 9).

Take for instance $[\hat{\sigma}_{y1} \hat{\sigma}_{x2} \hat{\sigma}_{x3}, \hat{\sigma}_{x1} \hat{\sigma}_{y2} \hat{\sigma}_{x3}]$; I think that I must not understand the implementation of the tensor products as my guess would be that $\hat{\sigma}_{y1} \hat{\sigma}_{x2} \hat{\sigma}_{x3} \hat{\sigma}_{x1} \hat{\sigma}_{y2} \hat{\sigma}_{x3} - \hat{\sigma}_{x1} \hat{\sigma}_{y2} \hat{\sigma}_{x3} \hat{\sigma}_{y1} \hat{\sigma}_{x2} \hat{\sigma}_{x3} = [\hat{\sigma}_{y1}, \hat{\sigma}_{x1}][\hat{\sigma}_{x2}, \hat{\sigma}_{y2}] \hat{\sigma}_{x3} \neq 0$. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(_^1 _^2_x^3)( _^1\sigma_^2_^3)\\=-\sigma_x^1_^1 _^2_x^3 \sigma_^2_^3\quad (x1,y1\, {\rm anticommute})\\
=+ \sigma_x^1\sigma_y^2_^1 _^2_x^3 _^3\quad (x2,y2 \,{\rm anticommute})\\
=+(_^1\sigma_^2_^3)(_^1 _^2_x^3)\quad  (x3,x3 \,{\rm commute})
$$
Everything else commutes.